# Problems with a card game

Tags: c#, uwp

For school i have to make a blackjack game in UWP. For me is this the first experience with UWP, so i can't figure out the problem.

If i click on a button a card needs to be added to my hand but i can't make it happen.

```
        private void ShowPlayer()
        {
            foreach (Card card in _hand.Cards)
            {
                Button btn = new Button()
                {
                    Height = 100,
                    Width = 75,
                    Content = new Image()
                    {
                        Height = 100,
                        Width = 75,
                        Source = card.Image
                    },
                    Tag = card
                };
                gvPLayer.Items.Add(btn);
            }
        }
```

this and

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                _hand.AddCard2(_deck.DrawCard());
            }
```

will add the first 2 given cards

but now i need on a Button click event that i add another card from my list. I'v tried this

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 2  ; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                _hand.AddCard(_deck.DrawCard());
            }
        }
```

For the deck code

```
        public Deck()
        {
            foreach (CardType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardType)))
            {
                foreach (CardValue value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardValue)))
                {
                    Card c = new Card(type, value);
                    cards.Add(c);
                    cards.Add(c);
                }
                foreach (CardValue value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardValue)))
                {
                    Card c = new Card(type, value);
                    cards1.Add(c);
                    cards1.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        public Card DrawCard()
        {
            Card c = cards[random.Next(cards.Count)];

            cards.Remove(c);

            return c;
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to share a little more code, as it stands, we probably need to see _deck.DrawCard() code, and how you expected your button click to work as it starts at 2 and while its <=1 (so never) add 1 to i.. perhaps this is why it doesnt work?

Comment: This won't fix the problem:(

Comment: Can you be more specific, as the loop listed has issues.. why wont it fix it, what specifically isnt then working

Comment: What is the difference between `.AddCard` and `.AddCard2`? More code is needed as you say one is working and not the other.

Comment: .Addcard is used for the player and .Addcard2 is for the dealer

Comment: If i click nothing happens at the moment

Comment: I fixed the problem, if forgot the Showplayer(); function after adding the card to it

Comment: If you have solved this issue, please your answer below and mark yourself.